# Find and copy files with ansible

Tags: linux, ansible

I want to make a script with ansible, to search on folder "/software" all the files, that were edited in the last day, then move them to "/tmp"

This my code so far (redhat 7.4):

```
 - name: recurse path
   find:
     path: /software
     recurse: yes
     file_type: file
     age: 1d
   register: files
 - name: copy files to tmp
   copy:
     src: ~/{{files}}
     dest: /tmp
```

I get the error:

```
an exeption occurred during task execution ... could not find or access '~{u'files': []}, u'changed': False, 'failed': False, u'examined': 4....
```

The folders have full access, so I dont think its permissions.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the first task is supposed to use the `find` module, right? the task looks missing the `find:` line. check the [module's documentation here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/find_module.html)

Answer (score 3):

As [documented](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/find_module.html#return-values), the returned value of the `find` module is an object containing the list of found files under the `files` keyword.

You cannot use it directly: `copy` module takes only 1 file or folder as `src`, so you have to loop over all the files:

```
- name: check the content and structure of the variable
  debug:
    var: files
- name: copy files to tmp
  copy:
    src: "{{item.path}}"
    dest: /tmp
  with_items: "{{files.files}}"
```

It's always a good practice to debug a var after `register` while developing to check it's structure (so you can find how to use it) and it's content (in your case, looks like the file list is empty).

BTW: you need to know that the `find` module search on the remote host but, by default, the `copy` module copies from the ansible executor machine, so in your case, the `src` may not exists! So if you are copying from local to remote, simply add `delegate_to: localhost` and `run_once: yes` to your `find` task, otherwise you need to use the `remote_src: yes` parameter on the `copy` task.